# Cloud Firestore: Missing or insufficient permissions but nothing changed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Since this morning I'm getting the following error:

```
Missing or insufficient permissions
```

I didn't change anything to the rules on firestore. I don't see where I'm getting this error from.

My DB rule is the standard: Allow only authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your `firestore.rules` file on your development machine. Note that this file / these rules can also be set via the Firebase console (website) and that they do have an initial/default value.

What probably happened is that you overwrote your `firestore.rules` file when you deployed your update.

Comment: I don't have a firestore.rules file since I was using the rules throught the Firebase console. Thing is.. in the morning all was ok and when I wanted to continue in the evening I suddenly got this error. I didn't touch those rules since april :s (Nothing is hosted.. still in development locally)

Comment: I could be wrong, but when you `firebase init` your firebase tools on your dev machine, `firestore.rules` is automatically created.

Comment: I'm using the angularfire2 package. Maybe because of this?

Comment: I got it solved. I started playing with the rules (and setting up individual rules and all seem ok atm)